# undefined local variable or method `shared_children'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, web-deployment

my `deploy.rb` is as follows

I keep getting the following error on `cap deploy:setup`

error message `var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/`capistrano-2.15.5`/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:122:in`method_missing_with_variables': undefined local variable or method `shared_children' for #<Capistrano::Configuration:0x00000000daf048> (NameError)`

capistrano version `capistrano-2.15.5`
rails version   `Rails 4.0.0`
ruby version `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410)`

any help will be highly apprecistaed

```
   require "rvm/capistrano"
   set :rvm_ruby_string, 'default'
   set :rvm_type, :user
   require "bundler/capistrano"

  set :application, "past" 

  set :ip, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"    
  set :domain,"paste.com"
  set :user, "okli"

   set :scm, :none
   set :repository, "."
  set :deploy_via, :copy

 set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{domain}" 
   set :use_sudo, false

namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
 end 

after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:copy_old_sitemap"
namespace :deploy do
  task :copy_old_sitemap do
    run "if [ -e #{previous_release}/public/sitemap.xml.gz ]; then cp #{previous_release}/public/sitemap* #{current_release}/public/; fi"
  end
end

after "deploy", "refresh_sitemaps"
task :refresh_sitemaps do
  run "cd #{latest_release} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} rake sitemap:refresh"
end


set :whenever_identifier, "homeworkly"
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
after "deploy:create_symlink", "deploy:update_crontab"  

namespace :deploy do  
  desc "Update the crontab file"  
  task :update_crontab, :roles => :db do  
    run "cd #{release_path} && whenever --update-crontab #{application}"  
  end  
end  

task :cleanup, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  count = fetch(:keep_releases, 2).to_i

  rsudo <<-CMD
    all=$(ls -x1 #{releases_path} | sort -n);
    keep=$(ls -x1 #{releases_path} | sort -n | tail -n #{count});
    remove=$(comm -23 <(echo -e "$all") <(echo -e "$keep"));
    for r in $remove; do rm -rf #{releases_path}/$r; done;
  CMD

  run <<-CMD
    rm -rf #{latest_release}/public/images &&
    ln -s #{shared_path}/images #{latest_release}/public/images
  CMD

  run <<-CMD
    rm -rf #{latest_release}/uploads &&
    ln -s #{shared_path}/uploads #{latest_release}/uploads
  CMD
end  

desc "tail production log files" 
task :tail_logs, :roles => :app do
  run "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/production.log" do |channel, stream, data|
    puts  # for an extra line break before the host name
    puts "#{channel[:host]}: #{data}" 
    break if stream == :err    
  end
end

after 'deploy:finalize_update', 'bundle:install'

after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the variable `shared_children` for Capistrano, I don't know why that's not done automatically (it's my tool, and I thought it worked)

Try simply:

```
set(:shared_children, [])
```

if you do not have any shared paths that you need to persist between deploys (which is unlikely in a Rails app, but might happen)

For the record Capistrano 2 is also unsupported now, you should upgrade to v3 which is faster and smoother and has better support and docs.